# Highcharts - Bubble losing focus without exiting the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bubble/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy'
},

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

title: {
    text: 'Sugar and fat intake per country'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.euromonitor.com/">Euromonitor</a> and <a href="https://data.oecd.org/">OECD</a>'
},

xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    title: {
        text: 'Daily fat intake'
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value} gr'
    },
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 65,
        label: {
            rotation: 0,
            y: 15,
            style: {
                fontStyle: 'italic'
            },
            text: 'Safe fat intake 65g/day'
        },
        zIndex: 3
    }]
},

yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    title: {
        text: 'Daily sugar intake'
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value} gr'
    },
    maxPadding: 0.2,
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 50,
        label: {
            align: 'right',
            style: {
                fontStyle: 'italic'
            },
            text: 'Safe sugar intake 50g/day',
            x: -10
        },
        zIndex: 3
    }]
},

tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.country}</h3></th></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Fat intake:</th><td>{point.x}g</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Sugar intake:</th><td>{point.y}g</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Obesity (adults):</th><td>{point.z}%</td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>'
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [
        { x: 95, y: 95, z: 13.8, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium' },
        { x: 86.5, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany' },
        { x: 80.8, y: 91.5, z: 15.8, name: 'FI', country: 'Finland' },
        { x: 80.4, y: 102.5, z: 12, name: 'NL', country: 'Netherlands' },
        { x: 80.3, y: 86.1, z: 11.8, name: 'SE', country: 'Sweden' },
        { x: 78.4, y: 70.1, z: 16.6, name: 'ES', country: 'Spain' },
        { x: 74.2, y: 68.5, z: 14.5, name: 'FR', country: 'France' },
        { x: 73.5, y: 83.1, z: 10, name: 'NO', country: 'Norway' },
        { x: 71, y: 93.2, z: 24.7, name: 'UK', country: 'United Kingdom' },
        { x: 69.2, y: 57.6, z: 10.4, name: 'IT', country: 'Italy' },
        { x: 68.6, y: 20, z: 16, name: 'RU', country: 'Russia' },
        { x: 65.5, y: 126.4, z: 35.3, name: 'US', country: 'United States' },
        { x: 65.4, y: 50.8, z: 28.5, name: 'HU', country: 'Hungary' },
        { x: 63.4, y: 51.8, z: 15.4, name: 'PT', country: 'Portugal' },
        { x: 64, y: 82.9, z: 31.3, name: 'NZ', country: 'New Zealand' }
    ]
}]
```

});

When I click on one of the bubble in the chart, the focus directs this clicked bubble. But i can not lose it unless mouse cursor is exiting the chart. Is there a way to reset focus right after mouse is not hovering on that bubble?

Comment: try this 

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/Lqszmet3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `hideDelay` option for tooltip to `0` and disable `stickyTracking` for series:

```
tooltip: {
    ...,
    hideDelay: 0
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stickyTracking: false,
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t57cLqrb/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.hideDelay

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bubble.stickyTracking